# Sort by SQL Count Used in WHERE Clause in ActiveRecord Scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to get a calculated column used during a scope declaration "where" clause passed on so that it is then useable in the returned set. I've tried this many different ways, and none work. Ultimately, what I am trying to accomplish is to ORDER the returned set by that count. Here is my scope so far:

```
scope :used_in_past, ->(days_ago) {
    where('(SELECT count(*) as total_tasks FROM grouptask WHERE creatorstudentid = sid AND creationdate > ?) > 0', Date.today-days_ago)
}
```

I'd like to "ORDER BY" total_tasks, and also hopefully pass it on to be used in a view. Whenever I try to use that named column it just says it doesn't exist, though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in the SQL sentence you could do that, with Alias or Function

```
SELECT COUNT(sid) AS total_tasks 
FROM grouptask
WHERE creatorstudentid = sid AND creationdate>0
GROUP BY sid
ORDER BY COUNT(sid);
```

I didn't see in your statement the **GROUP BY** section if you are using Aggregation Function Maybe you required

I hope this answer could help you

Regards